# 9-Speed Cassette: Shimano, Sunrace, Lanxuanr, other, does it matter?

Tags: cassette, compatibility

Looking to replace an old 9-speed cassette (SLX) which is long out of production and unavailable now. I see on Amazon some other Shimano 9-speed cassettes (Alivio or Sora as it's a commuter bike now), Sunrace, and Lanxuanr.

Does it make any difference? They seem to all range in cost from 25 to 35 GBP. I just want a smooth ride and no gear jumping.

The rear derailleur is a Shimano XT and so it the crankshaft and front rings, and shifters are SLX (all year 2011).

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

They are all very similar. They use various types of steel (or other more expensive materials in some parts) and even from one, manufacturer you can buy several models, some cheaper and some more expensive. For example, all Shimano models with the same sprocket sizes are compatible. They differ in the weight, price and perhaps some quality of manufacturing. Other manufacturers may have slightly different ramps that make gear changing easier but are mostly fully compatible and should shift well too.

For example, I now use a Microshift cassette with Shimano Claris rear derailleur and it works well.

Comment: The sprockets are made out of steel, not aluminium. The more expensive ones (e.g. Shimano Deore XT CS-M770-9) have an aluminium spider to which the biggest sprockets are attached (similar to chainrings on the front). The most expensive ones sometimes use titanium for all except the smallest sprockets (and sometimes aluminium for the biggest one).

Comment: Sorry, steel, of course. This is just a simple clerical error. I first wanted to write metal, but then I realized that there are just a few aluminium ones (in one part or another) but then I wrote aluminium instead of steel.